# Need help with map_saver

Tags: ros, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I'm a beginner to ros so I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I have been wanting to use the map_server package to save an OccupancyGrid. I found a tutorial for using map_saver but it was related to gmapping, which I am not using. In order to test it out, I created the following node to just publish a simple 2x2 OccupancyGrid. However when I run "rosrun map_server map_saver", it will say it is waiting for a map even though my node is running. I was wondering what I'm doing wrong here.
I am using Windows 10 and running ros on the Oracle Virtual Machine using Vagrant, and have roscore running.

#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import sys

from nav_msgs.msg import *

from std_msgs.msg import *

def mapMethod():

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('saved_maps', OccupancyGrid, queue_size=10)

rospy.init_node('saved_maps_node', anonymous=True)

X_VALUE = 2
Y_VALUE = 2
rate = rospy.Rate(0.5) #delay time (times per second)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    test_map = OccupancyGrid()
    
    test_map.info.width = X_VALUE
    test_map.info.height = Y_VALUE
    test_map.info.origin.position.x = 0
    test_map.info.origin.position.x = 0
    array = []
    for i in range(0, X_VALUE * Y_VALUE):
        array.append(1) 

    test_map.data = array

    pub.publish(test_map)

    print(test_map.data)
    rate.sleep()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
try:
mapMethod()
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
pass

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221677/need-help-with-map_saver/) by [jhajj96](https://answers.ros.org/users/25194/jhajj96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check your topics - I think map_saver will be subscribing to the topic /map and waiting for a map to be published on that topic

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0